# Google Translate API Key JSON on live server (Vercel)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, vercel, google-translate

I am using standard API keys in a `.env` file for most of my APIs. Now, the google translate API seems to require me to use the JSON format and do an EXPORT, before I start my server. e.g.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Path/To/API/Key.json"
```

This all works on my local machine, but I don't know how to do this same step on my production server? How can I complete this step (or do it another way), so i can use the translation API on my live server? I am using Vercel with NextJS but I guess the question is a more general one.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need a service account key file on your workstation. It's a bad security practice. It's better to avoid it. (sadly, even the Google documentation recommend to use it, and I'm often fighting with Google about that topic). So... Where will be your production server? On Google Cloud? Can you share your code where you call the translate API?

Comment: If you are using the host [Vercel](https://vercel.com), then you probably need to use a service account and set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. However, you do not define a problem, e.g. how you are using credentials. Edit your post to clearly define a problem to be solved. The Google Translate APIs support implicitly specifying the credentials (service account JSON key file) or can default to the env variable when running out side Google Cloud.

Comment: I have not used Vercel, but it states `Vercel is the platform for frontend developers`. Be very careful with credentials (API Keys, service account JSON key files, OAuth tokens). You do not want to expose those credentials in a repository or via frontend code.